# Ошибка чтения из файла в char*. C++

Tags: c++

### 1. Есть файл с данными:

- 1 Пароход1 200 Красный 2
- 2 Парусник1 150 Типтруб-2 4
- 3 Корвет1 120 Типтруб-1 3 Зелёный 20.

---

Первое - код для понимания, какой объект я буду инициализировать, остальные - поля классов.

---

```
   while (!fin.eof())
    {
        fin >> key;
        try{
            if (key == 1)
            {
                fin >> name >> speed >> color >> counttrumpet;
                Steamship *ss = new Steamship(name, speed, color, counttrumpet);
                l.push_back(ss);
            }
            if (key == 2)
            {
                fin >> name >> speed >> typesail >> countsail;
                Sailingship *ss = new Sailingship(name, speed, typesail, countsail);
                l.push_back(ss);
            }
            if (key == 3)
            {
                fin >> name >> speed >> typesail >> countsail >> colorsail >> age;
                Corvette *ct = new Corvette(name, speed, typesail, countsail, colorsail, age);
                l.push_back(ct);
            }
        }
```

---

При считывании name вылетает следующая ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как минимум, вот так `while (!fin.eof())` писать нельзя. О том, что достигнут конец файла, становится известно только **после** неудачного чтения.

Comment: Подозреваю, что ошибка может быть в коде перед while, где я инициализировал переменные char следующим образом:
char* colorsail="", *typesail="", *color="", *name="";

Comment: И что получается? `name` - указатель на 1 байт в памяти, которая еще и r/o (раз это VS), и вы туда хотите читать целые длинные имена... Воспользуйтесь хотя бы `string`, это проще всего...

Answer (score -1):

В целом, ошибка была весьма глупая.

```
char* colorsail="", *typesail="", *color="", *name="";
```

---

Когда нужно было инициализировать их так.

```
 char* colorsail = new char[20], *typesail = new char[20], *color = new 
 char[20], *name = new char[20];
```

Comment: Лучше бы избавиться от new. Строки читать в std::string. В контейнер помещать smart-pointers, построенные с помощью функций типа - `std::make_unique<>()`

Comment: А освобождать как потом? а почему именно 20? :) Вобщем, это C++, и не нужно придумывать пути посложнее...